# How to click on the element Dynamically in protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

My code

```
element.all(by.css('img.setimagepositionInactive')).filter(function (img, index) {
            return index ==3 ;
            }).each(function (img) {
                img.click();
            });
```

Using this code am clicking on 3rd element, next time if run the test case it should click on 4th element and again if am running the script it should click on 5th element,6th element,etc...

How to do it please help me

Comment: What do you mean by next time? Are you telling that you will stop running test scripts after the first round of and then do a second round of testing again by running them? Or is it that you want to run it in the same tests multiple times? Can you please elaborate? Thanks

Comment: @GirishSortur I will stop the test  after the first round and after some time again i will test.

Comment: If you are stopping the whole test from running, i am afraid there is no way you can save data from one test to another that is inbuilt in protractor. However you can use a separate file to save the count of element being clicked and update it everytime it runs using `fileStream` in javascript.

Comment: @GirishSortur Ok thank u so much. I asked one more question please reply

Comment: @GirishSortur Am not able to ask the question after 90 min only i can ask. it giving error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92375/discussion-between-girish-sortur-and-raghavendra-t).

Comment: @GirishSortur can i ask here only